# In the graph the part represent "0.0-2.0" is far from the center while "10-17" is close to the center. How to opposite the condition?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Wind Load Diagram

1. Save and Analyse the Data

Show the database first.

```
wind <- data.frame(
  Speed = c("0.0~2.0", "2.1~5.0", "5.1~7.0", "7.0~10.0", "10.1~17.0", ">17.0"),
  N = c(660,759,153,26,1,0),
  NNE = c(1261,2304,450,143,6,0),
  NE = c(954,1964,262,61,5,0),
  ENE = c(810,1540,161,36,4,0),
  E = c(898,1677,132,21,8,0),
  ESE = c(1003,3262,501,46,2,0),
  SE = c(882,2448,309,32,0,0),
  SSE = c(916,1916,89,12,0,0),
  S = c(890,1117,143,30,4,0),
  SSW = c(799,1026,152,34,0,0),
  SW = c(798,876,144,34,2,0),
  WSW = c(841,562,52,16,0,0),
  W = c(736,519,65,10,0,0),
  WNW = c(570,837,114,28,1,0),
  NW = c(895,1524,234,64,1,0),
  NNW = c(1169,2384,559,178,12,0),
  C = c(620,0,0,0,0,0)
)
print(wind)
```

Next, calculate the weight of each value.

```
wind_sum <- (colSums(wind[,-1]))
wind_sum <- sum(wind_sum)
wind[,-1] <- wind[,-1] / wind_sum
print(wind)
```

Assume that the maximum safe crosswind speed is 7.0. So, add the weight whose speed is lower than 7.0.

```
W_0_7 <-(rowSums(wind[1:3,-1]))
W_0_7 <- sum(W_0_7)
print(W_0_7)
```

2 Draw the Graph

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
wind_ = subset(wind, select = -C)
rose_long = melt(wind_, id.vars="Speed", variable.name ="Directions", value.name="Weights")
p <- ggplot(rose_long, aes(x=Directions, y=Weights, fill=Speed)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black")
p + 
  coord_polar() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  ylim(-0.025, 0.1) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.1) +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.border= element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank()
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently you do not include a question in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Speed` column is a factor whose levels are ordered alphabetically instead of a numerically meaningful way. You should redefine your factor using the following before you plot the graph:

```
speed <- c("0.0~2.0", "2.1~5.0", "5.1~7.0", "7.0~10.0", "10.1~17.0", ">17.0")
rose_long$Speed <- factor(rose_long$Speed, levels = speed, labels = speed)
```

You should get the following graph:

[image: example]